# Change $sql when clicking option in navbar

Tags: php, mysql

I want to change the `$sql` query when I click a option in the navbar. This is my navbar:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="subnav">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="">League </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">All</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Gold</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Silver</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Bronze</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my PHP

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `rating` > 74 ORDER BY `special` DESC , `rating` DESC  LIMIT 45";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error()); 
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)){
```

So when I pushed the button Gold I want the `$sql` to become

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `rating` > 74 AND `Revision` = 0 ORDER BY `special` DESC , `rating` DESC  LIMIT 45";
```

Sorry for still using mySQL , i'm updating it to PDO!

I hope you guys can help me,

Julan

Answer (score 2):

Is the following what you mean?

```
<html>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="subnav">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="index.php?type=league">League </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php?type=all">All</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php?type=gold">Gold</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php?type=silver">Silver</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php?type=bronze">Bronze</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>

<?php
if( !empty( $_GET['type'] ) ) {
$type = $_GET['type'];

if($type !== 'gold') {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `rating` > 74 ORDER BY `special` DESC , `rating` DESC  LIMIT 45";
} else {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `rating` > 74 AND `Revision` = 0 ORDER BY `special` DESC , `rating` DESC  LIMIT 45";
}
   $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error()); 
   while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)){

}
?>
```

**Case switch example:**

```
<?php
if( !empty( $_GET['type'] ) ) {
$type = $_GET['type'];

switch($type) {
 case 'league':
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `rating` > 74 ORDER BY `special` DESC , `rating` DESC  LIMIT 45";
  break;
 case 'all':
   // Some code here
   break;
case 'gold':
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `rating` > 74 AND `Revision` = 0 ORDER BY `special` DESC , `rating` DESC  LIMIT 45";
  break;
 // ETC.
}
   $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error()); 
   while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)){

}
?>
```

Comment: Something like that yes. But I want the user to choose 'gold' or 'silver' in the navbar and then get the sql

Comment: I only showed an example of what you could do. We are not here to write the complete code unless it's required to answer the question